# ERROR 000732 in code to Save shape as .lyr?

Tags: arcpy, error-000732, layer-file

I am using a code (modified from Midavalo) to save .shp files as .lry files. The code runs well and displays the .lr files in the table of Contents. However, the Python displays Runtime error. On the other hand, I don’t know how to save .lyr 
I need the .lyr files to export as .kml files

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
env.workspace = r"D:\ss3\polygons"
buf= r"D:\ss3\polygons\001.shp"
ou2= r"D:\ss3\layers\001.lyr"

arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(buf, 'buf_layer')
arcpy.SaveToLayerFile_management('buf_layer', ou2, "ABSOLUTE")
```

This the error:

> Runtime error  Traceback (most recent call last):   File "",
>   line 7, in    File "c:\program files
>   (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.5\arcpy\arcpy\management.py", line 6965, in
>   MakeFeatureLayer     raise e ExecuteError: ERROR 000732: Input
>   Features: Dataset D:\ss3\polygons\001.shp does not exist or is not
>   supported

Comment: Please include the error message in your question.

Comment: This the error: Runtime error  Traceback (most recent call last):   File "<string>", line 7, in <module>   File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.5\arcpy\arcpy\management.py", line 6965, in MakeFeatureLayer     raise e ExecuteError: ERROR 000732: Input Features: Dataset D:\ss3\polygons\001.shp does not exist or is not supported

Comment: Don't forget to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error suggests your path is incorrect or the shapefile does not exist in this directory:

```
buf = r"D:\ss3\polygons\001.shp"
```

At the minium to make a shapefile you need a .dbf, .shx, and .shp file in the same directory.

Comment: Now with your advice, I fixed the error.

Comment: @SebastianSalazar if the answer was that helpful then I think you should upvote it (like I just did) and click the green checkmark to Accept the answer.